# Confused about iOS notifications

Tags: android, ios, iphone, swift, notifications

I've read a lot about notifications in iOS now and I'm quite confused about how to reliably schedule notifications, actually. Let me explain my scenario:

I created an Android app that holds a fixed list of dates. The user can not add or remove dates, he can only view that list (garbage removal dates for my area). You can, however, configure that you want to be notified the day before. I've made that app so that when the device starts, a notification timer is started that fires at a certain time, checks whether there are pending items for the next day and if so, shows a notification. Then it re-schedules itself for the next day. So normally, the user doesn't need to open the app at all to receive notifications. He only opens the app once to configure his street, which triggers the first scheduled event, or to actually see the list of upcoming dates.

I'm now trying to port this app to iOS and I understand from what I've read that there's no way to replicate the way I'm doing stuff on Android. I understand that I can create up to 64 notifications for certain points of time in advance, but without the user opening the app at all I can not be sure to reliably schedule all the notifications I may need.

Is there a reliable way to simulate the described Android behavior? Or is there a way to force the user to open up the app once every 30 days or so?

Comment: Is there any pattern to the dates or are they just arbitrary?

Comment: They are actually more of less arbitrary. An additional "problem" is that there is no online functionality. That means, the app contains a fixed list of dates for 2017, the dates for 2018 will be provided as an app update. So while I could schedule most 2017 dates, I need to run the app once after the 2018 update.

Comment: Why was my question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell no.

If applicable you can make notifications repeating, but if the dates are random and you can't repeat the notification then you can't schedule more than the limit.

You can't schedule your app to run and you can't *force* the user to do anything. All you can do is post some sort of notification for 30 days or whenever with some message that you hope will compel them to open your app.

If you have a valid use case for it in your app, you can enable a background mode such as a location change on a cell tower transition for example, then when your app runs in the background re-schedule the notifications. Or remote push, or background fetch etc. But even with background modes you cannot guarantee your app will actually run in the background, you can just help to increase the chances that it might and the different background modes have different degrees of usefulness in this sort of area.

Comment: On iOS, if the user does not use the app, the application's background modes won't be a solution, so that's quite impossible, as you perfectly pointed in your answer

Comment: If the user doesn't use the app a signification location change trigger would still run it I believe (if not disabled by the user of course), but the others wouldn't. A silent remote push would run it provided the user hadn't terminated the app. Background fetch eventually peters out so is only good for several days.

Comment: Yes, but that is a quite bizarre technique and very hard to implement... And not very user-friendly, since it asks them to access their location

Comment: As an Android developer I find it equally bizarre to not be able to implement something as simple as a reliable "wake up call" for your own app...